# Select Data over time period

Tags: postgresql, select, time, epoch

I'm a bit of newbie when it comes to postgres, so bear with me a wee bit and i'll see if i can put up enough information.

i insert weather data into a table every 10 mins, i have a time column that is stamped with an epoch date.

I Have a column of the last hrs rain fall, and every hr that number changes of course with the running total (for that hour).

What i would like to do is skim through the rows to the end of each hour, and get that row, but do it over the last 4 hours, so i would only be returning 4 rows say.

Is this possible in 1 query? Or should i do multiple queries?

I would like to do this in 1 query but not fussed...

Thanks

---

Thanks guys for your answers, i was/am a bit confused by yours gavin - sorry:) comes from not knowing this terribly well.

I'm still a bit unsure about this, so i'll try and explain it a bit better..

I have a c program that inserts data into the database every 10 mins, it reads the data fom a device that keeps the last hrs rain fall, so every 10 mins it could go up by x amount. 
So i guess i have 6 rows / hr of data. 
My plan was to go back (in my php page) every 7, which would be the last entry for every hour, and just grab that value. Hence why i would only ever need 4 rows.. just spaced out a bit!

My table (readings) has data like this

```
index | time (text)  | last hrs rain fall (text)
1     | 1316069402   | 1.2
```

All ears to better ways of storing it too :) I very much appreciate your help too guys thanks.

Comment: so... are you really giving each row the running total for the hour of rainfall, rather than the total rainfall since the last row?  embedding periods into the data like that will make other queries much more difficult.  If it's difficult to get the rainfall only for that specific timeslice of 10 minutes, it might still be better to record the grand total rainfall since you began recording; since you can easily derive the timeslice rainfall from that data.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do it in one query...

Would something along the lines of:

```
SELECT various_columns,
    the_hour,
    SUM ( column_to_be_summed )
FROM ( SELECT various_columns,
            column_to_be_summed,
            extract ( hour FROM TIME ) AS the_hour
       FROM readings
      WHERE TIME > ( NOW() - INTERVAL '4 hour' ) ) a
GROUP BY various_columns,
    the_hour ;
```

do what you need?

Answer (score 2):

SELECT SUM(rainfall) FROM weatherdata WHERE time > (NOW() - INTERVAL '4 hour' );

I don't know column names but that should do it the ones in caps are pgsql types. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Hi Daniel, 
I tried this query 
select index,time from readings where time > cast(extract(epoch from (NOW() - INTERVAL '4 hour')) as text);
But it returns the last 4 hrs of data (ie, 24 10min samples)... where i was looking for more 1 result of each hour
something like 
4:00pm rowdata1 rowdata1
5:00pm rowdata1 rowdata1
6:00pm rowdata1 rowdata1
etc etc...
I think that i am probably better off to do multiple queries to find the data?

Comment: Yes or you could make a little function although i am really rubbish with functions so i would only direct you to the pgsql docs. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but perhaps it may serve as a basis for adaptation.
I often have a requirment for producing summary data over time periods though I don't use epoch time so there may be better ways of manipulating the values than I have come up with.

create and populate test table

```
create table epoch_t(etime numeric);
insert into epoch_t 
select extract(epoch from generate_series(now(),now() - interval '6 hours',interval '-10 minutes'));
```

To divide up time into period buckets:

```
select generate_series(to_char(now(),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:00:00')::timestamptz,
                       to_char(now(),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:00:00')::timestamptz - interval '4 hours', 
                       interval '-1 hour');
```

Convert epoch time to postgres timestamp:

```
select timestamptz 'epoch' + etime * '1 second'::interval from epoch_t;
```

then truncate to hour :

```
select to_char(timestamptz 'epoch' + etime * '1 second'::interval,
               'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:00:00')::timestamptz  from epoch_t
```

To provide summary information by hour :

```
select to_char(timestamptz 'epoch' + etime * '1 second'::interval,
               'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:00:00')::timestamptz,
       count(*)  
  from epoch_t 
 group by 1 
 order by 1 desc;
```

If you might have gaps in the data but need to report zero results use a generate_series to create period buckets and left join to data table.
In this case I create sample hour buckets back prior to the data population above - 9 hours instead of 6 and join on the conversion of epoch time to timestamp truncated to hour.

```
select per.sample_hour,
       sum(case etime is null when true then 0 else 1 end) as etcount
  from (select generate_series(to_char(now(),
                               'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:00:00')::timestamptz,
                               to_char(now(),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:00:00')::timestamptz - interval '9 hours', 
                               interval '-1 hour') as sample_hour) as per
       left join epoch_t on to_char(timestamptz 'epoch' + etime * '1 second'::interval,
                                    'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:00:00')::timestamptz = per.sample_hour
group by per.sample_hour
order by per.sample_hour desc;
```